# Can't access enum in a scope

Tags: ios, swift, enums, access-control

I have enum of images:

```
enum Images {
    enum MainIcons {
        static let disabledLike = UIImage(named: "disabledLike")
        static let enabledLike = UIImage(named: "enabledLike")
```

And a class for collection view cell, where I`d like to set an image for a button:

```
public class CardCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

lazy var favouriteButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .black
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()
...
// Some code


private func setupUI() {
        favouriteButton.setImage(Images.MainIcons.disabledLike?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        favouriteButton.setImage(Images.MainIcons.enabledLike?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .selected)
        
    }
}
```

However I keep getting error **Cannot find 'Images' in scope** .

What can be wrong?How can I access the enum?

Comment: Where is `Images` declared? Where is `CardCollectionViewCell` declared? Same bundle/target? Same framework? Etc.

Comment: @Larme Images are declared in Project > Helpers > Images.swift
&
CardCollectionViewCell declared in Project > UIKit > Cell > CardCollectionViewCell.swift

Comment: Make sure your file have a proper target.

Comment: @RajaKishan How can I check and edit target of those files?

Comment: select file and open file inspector. https://images.app.goo.gl/Drek45dD2Fkn296aA

Comment: @RajaKishan Thank you. Images` target is Project.app and cell`s target is UIKit.framework . What can I do?

Comment: cell`s target is UIKit.framework? Do you mean cell class file?

Comment: @RajaKishan yes, the target of CardCollectionViewCell.swift is UIKit.framework

Comment: change to project target same as other file targets.